# Selenium Find by Css help needed.-

Tags: c#, css, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Not a developer here.

I have two checkboxs  with No IDs. I am find with selenium when I have an ID. But in this case the table was created with jquery datatables and no process is present to auto assign the IDs.

In css the line below would should give me the first row in that table.

`#CompanyTableTable tr:first-of-type input[type="checkbox"].CompanySelector`

This one selects the second entry.

`#CompanyTable tr:nth-of-type(2) input[type="checkbox"].CompanySelector`

I think I should be able to use this inside the following? But all my attempts return different formating errors.

`driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("**Css_Here**???")).Click();`

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Can you provide the errors you get and add more context to the code that is run before the `.FindElement()`? It might be that the element simply cannot be found because it's not yet present.

Comment: is the tag you are trying to find, really `<CompanyTable>` ?  your CSS selector is trying to find `<CompanyTable><input type="checkbox" class="CompanySelector" /></CompanyTable>`

Comment: @sircapsalot this is a markup issue of Stackoverflow. His actual selector is this: `#CompanyTableTable tr:first-of-type input[type="checkbox"].CompanySelector`

Comment: ah, thanks.  there's an active edit. must fix that :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone.

I had to add a wait and the below worked for grabbing the second checkbox

driver.FindElement (By.CssSelector("tr.even > td > input.CompanySelector")).Click();

I installed the Firefox IDE and ran the interface and grabbed the formatting from that.